# Scala. Get first element of List

Tags: scala, list

Why does `queue.get(`) return empty list?

```
class MyQueue{
  var queue=List[Int](3,5,7)

  def get(){
    this.queue.head
  }
}

object QueueOperator {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val queue=new MyQueue
    println(queue.get())
  }
}
```

How i can get first element?

Comment: While you're learning, you might find it useful to explicitly write out more types than are necessary. In this case, if you'd written `def get(): Int { this.queue.head }` the compiler would have told you there was a problem with the `get` method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's not returning the empty list, it's returning `Unit` (a zero-tuple), which is Scala's equivalent of `void` in Java. If it were returning the empty list you'd see `List()` printed to the console rather than the `()` (nullary tuple).

The problem is you're using the wrong syntax  for your `get` method. You need to use an `=` to indicate that `get` returns a value:

```
def get() = {
  this.queue.head
}
```

Or this is probably even better:

```
def get = this.queue.head
```

In Scala you usually leave off the parentheses (parameter list) for nullary functions that have no side-effects, but this requires you to leave the parentheses off when you call `queue.get` as well.

You might want to take a quick look over the [Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/), specifically the [section on methods](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#methods).

Comment: Because of such mistakes, there is ongoing discussion about deprecating procedure syntax `def proc(...) { ... }` in favor of full form `def proc(...): Unit = { ... }`. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-debate/8G3WgfZNj9E

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can be good to use

take 1

instead of head because it doesnt cause an exception on empty lists and returns again an empty list.

Comment: `headOption` is better, because it doesn't use any magic constants (1), and it returns a type (`Option[T]`) that is statically guaranteed to be of maximum size 1.